# Query mysql database through memcache

Tags: mysql, innodb, memcached

I have been trying to use memcache with MySQL 5.6 but I can not figure out how to do this.

I have add an entry into innodb_memcache.containers so I can query the database through memcache.

What I would usually do with memcache is get the value for the key by doing this:

```
$value = $memcache->get($key);
```

but in mysql5.6 potentially there could be a lot of tables specified , so using PHP , how do I specify the table I am trying to query against using the memcache layer?.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation...

> To use an existing table with the memcached interface, define an entry for it in the `innodb_memcache.containers` table.
>
> To make that the table the default for all requests relayed through memcached, specify the value `default` in the name column, then restart the MySQL server to make that change take effect.
>
> If you are using multiple tables for different classes of memcached data, set up multiple entries in the `innodb_memcache.containers` table with name values of your choosing, then issue a memcached request of the form `get @@name` or `set @@name` within the application to switch the table used for subsequent requests through the memcached API.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-developing.html